# Adding an automatic timer PFObject to Parse.com Class

Tags: swift, amazon-web-services, time, parse-platform

I was wondering if this was possible. I am using parse.com and would like to create a PFObject that is a timer. For example, if I initially set the object to 60 seconds, the server will automatically start counting down the seconds until zero hits. I would like to be able to manually do this in parse.com, no need for code.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a subclass that extends Parse.Object, register it and manage this on your own.